# Different behaviour when running letsencrypt's certbot as a cron job

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

I have installed letsencrypt on Ubuntu 14.03 following this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

I also created a cron job for certificate renewal as described in the guide, but then found the following problem:

- `certbot-auto renew` (as a non-root user) and `sudo certbot-auto renew` both work when tested from the command line (certbot reports that the certificates are not due for renewal yet, as expected)
- However, when the same command is run by cron (as root), certbot tries to upgrade itself.

Any idea why I am getting this different behaviour? What is the difference between running the command manually on a shell console and having it run by cron?

**Update:** I added `--no-self-upgrade` but it didn't make any difference. On further investigation I noticed the following:

- `sudo certbot-auto renew --dry-run` works fine
- `sudo su; certbot-auto renew --dry-run` tries to upgrade certbot first

For some reason, certbot seems to think it is not properly installed when running in the second form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurs because of the way `certbot` was installed.

When not using a packaged distribution installation of `certbot`, it can't ensure that all dependencies are met so to make sure it can run properly, it creates a virtual environment in your `$HOME`. When running with `sudo`, this is still your own `$HOME`. However, when running as root, this turns to `/root` where the virtual environment is not present and thus, `certbot` cannot run without creating it. It's not upgrading itself so much as installing itself considering the new environment it is run from.

Comment: My doubt with this answer is: is it according to best practice to install certbot as root user? Thats the only way I accomplished to have the `certbot renew` command running on cron without problems.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

The issue here was that certbot-auto was first ran (initialized) using
sudo while cron ran it as the root user. This resultet in certbot-auto
trying to install dependenvies when executed by cron/root.

The solution would be to run certbot-auto as root, not using sudo.

I still want to mention --no-self-upgrade as this will keep certbot-auto
from trying to upgrade itself. Useful when executed by a cronjob as you
can/should monitor any upgrades by running it manually from time to time.

---

I do not see any difference when testing here on Debian Jessie using the latest certbot-auto. You could add '--no-self-upgrade' to the command. That way certbot-auto does not check for new versions.

I have this in '/etc/cron.d/letsencrypt'

```
# Check if we need to renew any certificates

4 4 * * * /opt/letsencrypt/certbot-auto renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade --post-hook "service nginx restart" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will run every once every day and then restart nginx if it had to renew any certificates but without trying to update certbot-auto itself.

Comment: I added --no-self-upgrade but it didn't help. I also found some extra info; please see the edit to my question.

Comment: Have you tried to allow certbot-auto to upgrade itself as root once?
Adding --no-self-upgrade should force it not to check for upgrades unless it is missing something.

Comment: That seems to be the problem indeed. But why is it triggered when running certbot as `sudo su; certbot-auto` but not when running as `sudo certbot-auto` ?

Comment: The difference between 'sudo su' and 'sudo' is a completely different question. But it is not the same.

Try to renew (or register a new cert) as the root user ('sudo su' first). Install/upgrade as certbot-auto wants. Then try running renew again using sudo. It should work. Maybe certbot-auto installed some dependencies locally on the user you used when running "sudo".